# Utilizar Node.js e PHP no mesmo servidor (Amazon EC2)

Tags: php, node.js, apache, amazon-aws

Meu site é feito "totalmente" em PHP e utilizei o Node.js para a parte do chat em tempo real. Estou usando os serviços da AWS e me surgiu uma grande dúvida:

Posso instalar o Node.js na mesma instância do PHP (apache) ou devo criar uma instância para o Node separadamente?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim você pode, Apache por padrão utiliza a porta 80 e você pode definir outra porta para o NodeJS como 8888.

Answer (score 3):

Conforme a resposta do Eduardo, você pode sim utilizar o APACHE junto com o NodeJS, em portas separadas. Aconselho você a colocar na FRENTE do NodeJS o APACHE ou NGINX como um proxy reverso, dessa forma é necessário apenas deixar liberado a porta padrão do HTTP (80 ou 443).

**Proxy reverso no NGINX**

http://www.devmedia.com.br/usando-nginx-como-proxy-reverso-e-diminuindo-o-consumo-do-servidor/21461

**Proxy reverso no APACHE**

https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/artigo/Proxy-Reverso-com-Apache